# How to show Hebrew variable in Stata

Tags: stata

I have a Stata Database with variables that are in Hebrew.

Is there a way to display the Hebrew letters?

My Windows language is Hebrew, so that's not the problem.

Comment: What have you tried? What happened? Stata doesn't support Unicode; that's a general statement.

Comment: I don't know what to try.. I succeeded to add Hebrew labels but that's not a solution for data in Hebrew. I once saw a friend using Stata with Hebrew so I'm sure there is a solution

Comment: I can see the Hebrew value in the value line, but not in the data editor

Comment: As a rule of thumb, whatever `asciiplot` (SSC) shows you for characters up to 255 is something you can work with.

Comment: `asciiplot` shows me Hebrew letters

Answer (score 1):

Answering myself:

if you have Hebrew on your computer, the way to display Hebrew characters correctly in stata is to change the font:

On the Data View Editor:

Right click on any variable -> Font -> Change the font to a font that has Hebrew.

Thanks to [I.M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2922682/i-m), [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231311/importing-foreign-languages-from-csv-file-to-stata) helped me to figured it out.